# How to freeze some part of the variable in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I've noticed that a variable can be frozen by setting `trainable=False`. I'm wondering how to freeze only part of it instead of splitting it into two variables.

For example, I only want to freeze the first element in `v = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2])`. It seems that `grad_new = tf.multiply(grad, np.array([0,1]))` doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think this will be possible. TF performs parallel computation on its tensors therefore the same operation must be done on all the components of each tensor

Comment: Sorry for the unclear representation. The `grad` is the one for `v` which computed in `grads = opt.compute_gradients(total_loss)`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

`grad_new = tf.multiply(grad, np.array([0,1]))` actually works quite well. It's the saver who mess up the code.